# i get Uncaught (in promise): Run init() first! error when i lunch my app

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm getting an error "Uncaught (in promise): Run init() first!", when I'm launch my application. I guess the error is caused by the firebase component inside the  **ngOnInit()**
Here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BackendService, FirebaseService } from "../services";
import { ListView } from 'ui/list-view';
import { TextField } from 'ui/text-field';
import { ScrollView } from 'ui/scroll-view';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "chat-tab",
    templateUrl: "chat.tab.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["chat.tab.component.css"]
})

export class ChatTabComponent implements OnInit {

    public constructor(
        private firebaseService: FirebaseService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.me = BackendService.token;
        this.chats$ = <any>this.firebaseService.getChats();       
    }


    public me: String;
    @ViewChild("list") lv: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("textfield") tf: ElementRef;
    list: ListView;
    textfield: TextField;
    public chats$: Observable<any>;

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.list = this.lv.nativeElement;
        this.textfield = this.tf.nativeElement;
    }

    scroll(count:number){
       console.log("scrolling to ", count)
       this.list.scrollToIndex(count-1);
       this.list.refresh();
    }

    chat(message: string) {
        this.firebaseService.chat(message).then((data: any) => {
            let count = this.list.items.length;

            this.scroll(count);
        });
        this.textfield.text = '';        
    }

    filter(sender) {

        if (sender == BackendService.token) {
             return "me";
        } 
        else {
            return "them"
        } 
    }

    align(sender) {

        if (sender == BackendService.token) {
            return "right"
        }
        else {
            return "left"
        }
    }

    showImage(sender) {

        if (sender == BackendService.token) {
            return "collapsed"
        }
        else {
            return "visible"
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the firebase.service

```
import {Injectable, NgZone} from "@angular/core";
import {User, Yowl} from "../models";
import { BackendService } from "./backend.service";
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

    constructor(
        private ngZone: NgZone,
    ){}

    yowls: BehaviorSubject<Array<Yowl>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    private _allYowls: Array<Yowl> = [];
    chats: BehaviorSubject<Array<Yowl>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    private _allChats: Array<Yowl> = [];

    getMessage(){ 
        firebase.addOnMessageReceivedCallback(function (data ){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
    }

    register(user: User) {

        return firebase.createUser({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }).then(
            function (result:any) {
                return JSON.stringify(result);
            },
            function (errorMessage:any) {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
        )

    }

    login(user: User) {

        return firebase.login({
            type: firebase.LoginType.PASSWORD,
            passwordOptions: {
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }
        }).then((result: any) => {
            BackendService.token = result.uid;
            return JSON.stringify(result);
        }, (errorMessage: any) => {
            alert(errorMessage);
        });
    }

    logout(){
        BackendService.token = "";
        firebase.logout();    
    }

    resetPassword(email) {
        return firebase.resetPassword({
            email: email
        }).then((result: any) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        function (errorMessage:any) {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
        ).catch(this.handleErrors);
    }  

    getYowls(): Observable<any> {

        return new Observable((observer: any) => {
            let path = 'Yowls';
            let onValueEvent = (snapshot: any) => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    let results = this.handleSnapshot(snapshot.value);
                    observer.next(results);
                });
            };

            firebase.addValueEventListener(onValueEvent, `/${path}`);
        }).share();              
    }

    handleSnapshot(data: any) {
        //empty array, then refill and filter
        this._allYowls = [];
        if (data) {
            for (let id in data) {         
                let result = (<any>Object).assign({id: id}, data[id]);
                this._allYowls.push(result);
            }
            this.publishUpdates();
        }

        return this._allYowls;
    }

    getChats(): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable((observer: any) => {
            let path = 'Chats';
            let onValueEvent = (snapshot: any) => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    let results = this.handleChatSnapshot(snapshot.value);
                    observer.next(results);
                });
            };

            firebase.addValueEventListener(onValueEvent, `/${path}`);
        }).share();              
    }

    handleChatSnapshot(data: any) {
        //empty array, then refill and filter
        this._allChats = [];
        if (data) {
            for (let id in data) {        
                let result = (<any>Object).assign({id: id}, data[id]);
                this._allChats.push(result);
            }
            this.publishChatUpdates();
        }

        return this._allChats;
    }

    sendYowl(Yowl:any) {
        let yowl = Yowl;   
        return firebase.push(
            "/Yowls",
            { "name": "Mr. Growlllr", "username": "MrGrwwlr", "text": "Yooowwwwlll!", "UID": BackendService.token, "date": 0 - Date.now()}
        ).then(
            function (result:any) {
                return 'Yowwled!';
            },
            function (errorMessage:any) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }); 
        }

    chat(message:string) {
        //let chat = Chat; 
        console.log(message)  
        return firebase.push(
            "/Chats",
            { "message": message, "to": "MrGrwwlr", "from": BackendService.token, "date": 0 - Date.now()}
        ).then(
            function (result:any) {
                return "chatted";
            },
            function (errorMessage:any) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }); 
        }

    publishUpdates() {
        this._allYowls.sort(function(a, b){
            if(a.date < b.date) return -1;
            if(a.date > b.date) return 1;
            return 0;
        })

        this.yowls.next([...this._allYowls]);
    }

    publishChatUpdates() {
        this._allChats.sort(function(a, b){
            if(a.date > b.date) return -1;
            if(a.date < b.date) return 1;
            return 0;
        })

        this.chats.next([...this._allChats]);
    }

    handleErrors(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        return Promise.reject(error.message);
    }
}
```

here is the app.component.ts file,it works fine it shows no errors but maybe am missing something

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
const dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
import { BackendService } from "./services/backend.service";



@Component({
  selector: "main",
  template: "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"

})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit(): void {

firebase.init({

  /*onPushTokenReceivedCallback: function(token) {

    alert("Firebase push token: " + token);

  },*/

  onMessageReceivedCallback: function(message) {

    dialogs.alert({

      title: "Push message: " + (message.title !== undefined ? message.title : ""),

      message: JSON.stringify(message.body),

      okButtonText: "W00t!"

    });

  },

  //persist should be set to false as otherwise numbers aren't returned during livesync

  persist: false,

  //storageBucket: 'gs://yowwlr.appspot.com',

  onAuthStateChanged: (data: any) => {

    if (data.loggedIn) {

      BackendService.token = data.user.uid;

    }

    else {

      BackendService.token = "";

    }

  }

}).then(

    function (instance) {

      console.log("firebase.init done");

    },

    function (error) {

      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);

      }
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the firebase init method in your app.ts file.If not paste the following code in app.ts file.

```
     `const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");`

           `firebase.init({
                   // Optionally pass in properties for database, 
                               authentication and cloud messaging,
                   // see their respective docs.
              }).then(
               instance => {
                             console.log("firebase.init done");
                            },
                error => {
                            console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
                         }
                         );
```

`

Comment: is the register function working fine? If not make sure you have put google service json in app resources folder and the package name in app.gradle  and the json is the same

Comment: yes i already have google service file and i checked the package names they are the same and all work fine,,but still facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what is exactly solution in angular

But i'm using vue js with nativescript

using this.$nextTick()
 worked for me 
may be there's something relevant in angular

my code

```js
var _this = this
this.$nextTick(() => {
 firebase.getValue('path')
  .then(result => {
    console.log('result:',result)
   })
  .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error)) 
});
```